# Can I use @FXML annotation for function variables?

Tags: netbeans, javafx-2, netbeans-7, fxml

I have an fxml file and i have a Button in it with id = "startButton"
now i should be able to use it in my code like this:

```
@FXML
Button startButton;
startButton.addActionLisetner...
```

but NetBeans says : annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration

how can i fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@FXML` only in `Controller` which is specifically set in fxml file and only for **fields** of that class.

This is required because these fields would be initialized automatically during creation of that class' object.

```
public class MyController implements Initializable{
     @FXML
     Button startButton;

     void initialize(java.net.URL location, java.util.ResourceBundle resources) {
          startButton.addActionLisetner(...);
     }
}
```